# Does the current lose kinetic energy , potential energy, or a combination of the two?

Tags: electrical-resistance

When an electric current passes through a resistor , the current loses energy, transferring thermal energy to the resistor. Does the current lose kinetic energy , potential energy, or a combination of the two?

Comment: My advice is to take an interest in finding the speed and mass of the charge-carriers (electrons), then you can do the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

When the voltage is switched on, the electric field pushes electrons through the resistor. Initially they accelerate due to the electric field, gaining kinetic by losing potential energy. After a short transitional time, the resistance causes the electronic drift speed to stabilise. From that moment on, potential energy continues be list but is converted into heat.